# Flip the order of the bars (y axis) in a horizontal barplot() (base R)

Tags: r, plot, graph, bar-chart

I have been searching for a solution to my presumably basic problem but have not found one!

I'm working with the data below `uk_twit_dm_semantic`:

```
structure(c(0.02, 0.98, 0, 1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.82, 0.18, 0.98, 0.02, 
0.05, 0.95, 0.41, 0.59, 0.81, 0.19, 0.32, 0.68, 0.9, 0.1, 0.45, 
0.55), .Dim = c(2L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(c("EE", "ER"), c("will can", 
"will shall", "would could", "would might", "will might", "would should", 
"will should", "will would", "will could", "will may", "Total"
)))
```

I am working on a horizontal stacked barplot of this data but I would like the order of the bars to be reversed (e.g. will can to be the top-most bar followed by each element of the vector until "Total", the bottom-most bar). For some reason horiz=TRUE gives me the reverse order. How can I flip the order?

```
barplot(uk_twit_dm_semantic, col=coul, border="white", horiz=TRUE,legend=rownames(uk_twit_dm_semantic))
```

[image]

All the best,

Cameron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea could be to reverse the columns order of your data-frame before launching plot code line

```
# 1- Reversing order of columns   
uk_twit_dm_semantic_rev <- uk_twit_dm_semantic[, rev(colnames(uk_twit_dm_semantic))]

# 2- Launching the plot with reversed columns
barplot(uk_twit_dm_semantic_rev, col=coul, border="white", horiz=TRUE, legend=rownames(uk_twit_dm_semantic_rev))
```

Answer (score 2):

same idea using order and col:

```
barplot(uk_twit_dm_semantic[,order(ncol(uk_twit_dm_semantic):1)],col=c("red","blue"), border="white", horiz=TRUE,legend=rownames(uk_twit_dm_semantic))
```

[image]